# jQuery function attr() doesn't always update img src attribute

Tags: javascript, jquery, image, src

Context: On my product website I have a link for a Java webstart application (in several locations).

My goal: prevent users from double-clicking, i. e. only "fire" on first click, wait 3 secs before enabling the link again. On clicking, change the link image to something that signifies that the application is launching.

My solution works, except the image doesn't update reliably after clicking. The commented out debug output gives me the right content and the mouseover callbacks work correctly, too.

See it running here: http://www.auctober.de/beta/ (click the Button "jetzt starten").

BTW: if anybody has a better way of calling a function with a delay than that dummy-animate, let me know.

JavaScript:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
      <!--
        allowClick = true;
        linkElements = "a[href='http://www.auctober.de/beta/?startjnlp=true&rand=1249026819']";
        $(document).ready(function() {
            $('#jnlpLink').mouseover(function() {
                if ( allowClick ) {
                    setImage('images/jetzt_starten2.gif');
                }
            });
            $('#jnlpLink').mouseout(function() {
                if ( allowClick ) {
                    setImage('images/jetzt_starten.gif');
                }
            });

           $(linkElements).click(function(evt) {
                if ( ! allowClick ) {
                    evt.preventDefault();
                }
                else {
                    setAllowClick(false);
                    var altContent = $('#jnlpLink').attr('altContent');
                    var oldContent = $('#launchImg').attr('src');
                    setImage(altContent);
                    $(this).animate({opacity: 1.0}, 3000, "", function() {
                        setAllowClick(true);
                        setImage(oldContent);
                    });
                }
            });

        });

        function setAllowClick(flag) {
            allowClick = flag;
        }
        function setImage(imgSrc) {
            //$('#debug').html("img:"+imgSrc);
            $('#launchImg').attr('src', imgSrc);
        }
      //-->
</script>
```

Comment: update: it seems to be browser-specific

It never works on Safari, it sometimes works on IE (though sometimes it displays no image at all and it sometimes works on Firefox (3.5). The strange thing is that it works on Firefox if I open the page through the file system instead of serving it with a webserver (locally or remote).

Ah the pains of web development...

Comment: update: opera does it fine, though :P

Answer (score 1):

A delay can be achieved with the setTimeout function

```
setTimeout(function() { alert('something')}, 3000);//3 secs
```

And for your src problem, try:

```
$('#launchImg')[0].src = imgSrc;
```

Comment: But as with other attributes, it doesn't always work correctly.
(Try doing element.setAttribute('class', 'someClass')) in IE. Same with colspan.

altering the .src attribute does not produce the same behavior in javascript as setAttribute('src', '...');

jQuery always returns an array, if you want the element, not the jQuery object, you need to use [0];

Comment: Although I agree with Sohnee that it's strange, I'm upvoting to get rid of the downvote because, indeed, it's worth _trying_.

Comment: There's nothing wrong with `$('#launchImg')[0]`.  Sometimes you want to get at the real DOM object and this beats a function call.

Answer (score 0):

Check out the [BlockUI](http://malsup.com/jquery/block/) plug-in. Sounds like it could be what you're looking for.

You'll find a nice demo [here](http://malsup.com/jquery/block/#page).

Comment: Ah, no, sorry, I don't want to block the whole UI, just the link.

Comment: OK. I see. You could also use it to just block an element but it might not be what you're looking for either. http://malsup.com/jquery/block/#element

Answer (score 0):

...or just use:

```
$(this).animate({opacity: '1'}, 1000);
```

wherever you want in your code, where $(this) is something that is already at opacity=1...which means everything seemingly pauses for one second. I use this all the time.

Answer (score -2):

Add this variable at the top of your script:

```
var timer;
```

Implement this function:

```
function setFlagAndImage(flag) {
    setAllowClick(flag);
    setImage();
}
```

And then replace the dummy animation with:

```
timer = window.setTimeout(function() { setFlagAndImage(true); }, 3000);
```

If something else then happens and you want to stop the timer, you can just call:

```
window.clearTimeout(timer);
```

Comment: Don't pass a string to window.setTimeout as it calls eval() and slows things down.

Comment: Eval is completely unnecessary for this. `setTimeout(function() { setFlagAndImage(true); }, 3000);` is preferred.